# Routing execute component before all

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem, I have  `ProductsService` which call data from the server and store in the `Array` and I have `ProductsComponent` component which is parent component and I have `ProductsListComponent` and `ProductListItemsComponent` which is children component. Flow is, In  `ProductsService` I have method:

```
 getCategoryFromServer() {
    this.dataStorageServiceServiceta.getCategory().subscribe((category: CategoryModel[]) => {
      this.categoryModule = category;
      this.cateogoryChange.next(this.categoryModule.slice())
    })
  }
```

And I have `categoryModule` array where data is stored.

In the `ProductsComponent` in the `ngOnInit` method I call the `getCategoryFromServer` method:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.productsService.getCategoryFromServer();
  }
```

And template for `ProductsComponent` is:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <app-products-list></app-products-list>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row" >
            <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

I my screen is shown `app-products-list` component where I call data from the `serevice` you can see on the image how look like. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81ceo.png). When I click on the some items in this list, using  `[routerLink]="[products.name]"` my component `ProductListItemsComponent` is shown and look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM4QX.png).
Problem is when i refresh page and first is executed `ProductListItemsComponent` and after that `ProductsComponent` and my array is empty. Do you know how I can resolve this problem?

My routing module is :

```
const productsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'productsList', component: ProductsComponent, children: [

            { path: ':category', component: ProductListItemsComponent },



        ]
    },

]
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(productsRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class ProductsRoutingModule {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this for once....

```
const productsRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'productsList', pathMatch: 'full' },

    {
        path: 'productsList', component: ProductsComponent, 
        children: [
            { path: ':category', component: ProductListItemsComponent },
        ]
    }
]
```

if it didn't work provide me stackbliz i will solve it for you.

Comment: This is not work. It is same problem exist. I will provide code.

Comment: can you provide stackbliz example

Comment: You can download from `github https://github.com/milos2611/angular-shop.git` github.

Comment: if you see more mistake, let me know.